# Metropolis-Hastings with two dimensional target distribution

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

I'm confused in the following situation:

I want to sample by writing code (Java) from the following distribution that is characterized by the mean vectors and covariance matrices:

$$
p\left ( \mathbf{x} \right ) = \frac{w_{1}}{2\pi \sqrt{\left | \mathbf{C}_{1} \right |}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left ( \mathbf{x}-\mu _{1} \right )^{\top }C_{1}^{-1}\left ( \mathbf{x}-\mu _{1} \right )}  +  \frac{w_{2}}{2\pi \sqrt{\left | \mathbf{C}_{2} \right |}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left ( \mathbf{x}-\mu _{2} \right )^{\top }C_{2}^{-1}\left ( \mathbf{x}-\mu _{2} \right )}
$$
where for $$ i = 1, 2, \mu_{i} \hspace{35pt} \mathrm{and}\hspace{35pt}  \mathbf{C}_{i}$$ are respectively the mean vectors and the covariance matrices.
$$ (\mathbf{x}-\mu _{i})^{\top } $$ is the row vector corresponding with the column vector $$ (\mathbf{x}-\mu _{i}) $$

We assume that the first and second mean are the column vectors 
$$ \boldsymbol{\mu }_{1} = (0,0)^{\top } \enspace \mathrm{and }\enspace \boldsymbol{\mu }_{1} = (d,0)^{\top }
 $$ and the first and second covariance matrices are 
$$ \mathbf{C}_{1} = \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma _{1} & 0\\ 
0 & \sigma _{2}
\end{pmatrix} \enspace \mathrm{and }\enspace \mathbf{C}_{2} = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
b & d
\end{pmatrix} \enspace \mathrm{respectively}. $$

Furthermore, $$ w_{1} = 0.7 ,\thinspace  w_{2} = 0.3 $$ and $$ \mu _{1} = \binom{4}{5}, \mu _{2} = \binom{0.7}{3.5}, \mathbf{C}_{1} = \begin{pmatrix}
1.0 & 0.7\\ 
0.7 & 0.1
\end{pmatrix},$$ and $$ \mathbf{C}_{2} = \begin{pmatrix}
1.0 & -0.7\\ 
-0.7 & 1.0
\end{pmatrix} $$

Since I'm using symmetric proposal distributions in the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm, the acceptance probability reduces to
[image]

where $$ \mathbf{x} \enspace \mathrm{and } \enspace \mathbf{x}^{*} $$ are respectively the current state and the proposed new state accepted with probability $$ A(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{x}^{*}) $$

I want to sample for both the Gaussian distribution and the uniform distribution.
The Gaussian distribution is 
$$ q(\mathbf{x^{*}},\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{\left | \mathbf{C} \right |}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x^{*}-x})^{\top }\mathbf{C^{-1}}(\mathbf{x^{*}}-\mathbf{x})} $$ where $$ \mathbf{C} = \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma  & 0\\ 
 0& \sigma 
\end{pmatrix} $$
The uniform distribution is over the square $$ [x_{1} - r, x_{1} + r] \times [x_{2} - r, x_{2} + r]$$
$$ q(\mathbf{x^{*}},\mathbf{x}) = \begin{Bmatrix}
\frac{1}{4r^{2}} & \mathrm{for} \enspace x_{1}^{*} \in  [x_{1} - r, x_{1} + r]\enspace \mathrm{and } \enspace x_{2}^{*} \in  [x_{2} - r, x_{2} + r]\\ 
0 & \mathrm{otherwise}
\end{Bmatrix} $$

I'm stuck in how to implement this in order to be able to do the sampling.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^{(i)}$ be the current value in the chain. Using the normal proposal distribution as an example, sample $x^* \sim N(x^{(i)}, C)$ and set $x^{(i+1)} = x^*$ with probability $A(x^{(i)},x^*)$ and otherwise set $x^{(i+1)} = x^{(i)}$.